# issue with ansible installation using RPM's

Tags: python, installation, ansible, rpm

Facing issue with Ansible installation using RPM's.

file /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/babel/localedata/st_LS.dat conflicts between attempted installs of python26-babel-0.9.5-2.el5.noarch and python-babel-0.9.5-3.1.noarch

The installation was successful on other server and working fine.
But when I am trying on different server, facing this error.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

two rpm packages cannot provide the same file; so that means they have not been well packaged. Probably you can get around using `force`; but that won't be a real solution; the resulting file on your file system will be on of both packages...

```
rpm -ivh --force python26-babel-0.9.5-2.el5.noarch.rpm
```

I note also that you are using one rpm that was made for centos (el5) and another that wasn't. Please first try to use rpms that were made for your distribution.

Comment: The installation using this RPM's is successful on one server and is failing on another. Both are Linux machines. Just want to know what all different things I can compare on these boxes.

Comment: sorry; small i for install

Comment: Thanks, this has helped. I am able to install ansible. But couple of rpms threw dependency error. Do you have any idea what these rpms are used for or what would happen if we ignore these... just asking for information sake....!!
rpm -ivh --force python-simplejson-2.0.9-8.el5.x86_64.rpm
warning: python-simplejson-2.0.9-8.el5.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID e8562897: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
        python(abi) = 2.4 is needed by python-simplejson-2.0.9-8.el5.x86_64

Comment: what it says: you are missing some dependencies. Why are you downloading all rpms manually; it is better to use a package manager (yum, zypper, whatever is on your os)